# begin sys.dbms_application_info.set_module('PL/SQL Developer', :action); end;

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

```
begin sys.dbms_application_info.set_module('PL/SQL Developer', :action); end;
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Please see https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  The first result from Google for 'sys.dbms_application_info' shows the Oracle documentation and the second shows an example from the Oracle community on Toadworld. Some basic research would have helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the version but the package is pretty similar through the versions.  This is a mechanism in the PL/SQL code to tag processes in the database with information that can be used for gathering tracing data or monitoring activity.

[Here is the link to the documentation for dbms_application_info for version 12.1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_appinf.htm#ARPLS003)